# Datagrip Intellij Cassandra SSL connection

Tags: ssl, intellij-idea, cassandra, datagrip, dbvisualizer

Looking for any suggestions connecting with an SSL enabled Cassandra cluster with Datagrip / Intellij / DBVisualizer or any other DB admin tool.

[image]

Solution #1

I've tried using the PEM files in the Intellij SSL tab that used for connecting with cqlsh. These do not work. The PEM files do work with cqlsh.

Solution #2
Wondering if there there are some properties to enable SSL. I've tried the following with JKS keystore and Truststore files:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=`

With these properties Intellij / Datagrip does not seem to connect via SSL I feel like a missing property is necessary to enable it.

Connecting with a local non-ssl enable cluster works fine. Any advise would be appreciated with connecting with an SSL enabled cluster.

Comment: Have you tried these steps https://www.simba.com/products/Cassandra/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/ca/ssl/intro.htm ?

Comment: `I've tried the following with JKS keystore and Truststore files:` In DataGrip/IntelliJ IDEA you should set JVM options for the database process in **VM Options** field in the **Advanced** tab of Data Source properties dialog.

Comment: @Andrey This does not work with the included driver with DataGrip/Intellij. I've made a pull request with the included driver that resolves the issue. https://github.com/DataGrip/cassandra-jdbc-driver/pull/1

Comment: Is this fixed with the driver available in DG 2019.1.3? I am still having the same problem: `java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format.Cannot initialize SSL Context`